# Inverse function and fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

> Let $f$ be the function defined by $$f(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1+|\sin xt^2|}{2}dt$$
> which has an inverse function denoted by $g$. Find the derivative $g'(0)$

When $f(x) = 0$, I see that $x = 1$ is a solution. So I need to find $g'(0)=\frac{1}{f'(1)}$.

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$f'(x) = \frac{1+|\sin x^3|}{2}$$
$$f'(1)=\frac{1+\sin 1}{2}$$

However there is no such answer (the question is in the form of MCQ). I wonder where did I go wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot about the chain rule (or Leibniz rule as it is called in this special case). Fundamentally theorem of calculus takes the derivative with respect to the $x$ in the bounds of the integral, but then you still have to separately take the derivative with respect to the $x$ in the integrand.

Comment: To avoid this issue altogether, use a change of variables to eliminate the $x$ from the integrand entirely.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Do you mean that $f'(x) = \frac{1+|\sin x^3|}{2}$ is wrong?

Comment: yes that is the issue, that derivative is wrong

Comment: Which answers are there?

Comment: @J.G. The available answers are -2, 2, -1, 1, and 0

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if the integral's lower limit, $1$, is a typo for $0$.

Comment: @J.G. It could possibly be a typo by the author.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac12\int_1^x \left(1+|\sin(xt^2)|\right)\,dt$.   Then, the derivative of $f$ at $x=1$, $f'(1)$, is given by

$$\begin{align}
f'(1)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-\overbrace{f(1)}^{=0}}{h}\\\\
&\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac12\int_1^{1+h}\left(1+|\sin((1+h)t^2)|\right)\,dt}{h}\\\\
&=\frac{1+\sin(1)}{2}
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Use the substitution $\sqrt{x}t = s$

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x^3}}1+|\sin(s^2)|\:ds$$

and now apply chain rule.